# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET while generating OTP code in sendotp.msg91 api?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want to implement a otp password for my website for that i choose sms gateway for OTP is sendotp.msg91 api , i signed-up into the website and created application got key for that, then i received the code for php and JavaScript , i changed my API key in php file as given below and other configuration and i hosted it into local host but it is showing error  jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/sms/sendotp.php?action=generateOTP net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET below are my code

SENDOTP.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
class SendOTP
{
    private $baseUrl = "https://sendotp.msg91.com/api";
    public function callGenerateAPI($request)
    {
        $data        = array(
            "countryCode" => $request['countryCode'],
            "mobileNumber" => $request['mobileNumber'],
            "getGeneratedOTP" => true
        );
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $ch          = curl_init($this->baseUrl . '/generateOTP');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'application-Key: APP KEY'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
    public function saveOTP($OTP)
    {
        //save OTP to your session
        $_SESSION["oneTimePassword"] = $OTP;
        // OR save the OTP to your database
        //connect db and save it to a table
        return true;
    }
    public function generateOTP($request)
    {
        //call generateOTP API
        $response = $this->callGenerateAPI($request);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if ($response["status"] == "error") {
            //customize this as per your framework
            $resp['message'] = $response["response"]["code"];
            return json_encode($resp);
        }
        //save the OTP on your server
        if ($this->saveOTP($response["response"]["oneTimePassword"])) {
            $resp['message'] = "OTP SENT SUCCESSFULLY";
            return json_encode($resp);
        }
    }
    public function verifyOTP($request)
    {
        //This is the sudo logic you have to customize it as needed.
        //your verify logic here
        if ($request["oneTimePassword"] == $_SESSION["oneTimePassword"]) {
            $resp['message'] = "NUMBER VERIFIED SUCCESSFULLY";

        } else {
            $resp['message'] = "OTP INVALID";

        }
        return json_encode($resp);
        // OR get the OTP from your db and check against the OTP from client
    }

    public function verifyBySendOtp($request)
    {
        $data        = array(
            "countryCode" => $request['countryCode'],
            "mobileNumber" => $request['mobileNumber'],
            "oneTimePassword" => $request['oneTimePassword']
        );
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $ch          = curl_init($this->baseUrl . '/verifyOTP');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'application-Key: Your-application-key'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        if ($response["status"] == "error") {
            //customize this as per your framework
            $resp['message'] = $response["response"]["code"];

        } else {
            $resp['message'] = "NUMBER VERIFIED SUCCESSFULLY";
        }
        return json_encode($resp);
    }
}
$sendOTPObject = new SendOTP();
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !empty($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    echo $sendOTPObject->$_REQUEST['action']($_REQUEST);
} else {
    echo "Error Wrong api";
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">                     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendOTP() {
var ccode=document.getElementById('cCode').value;
var number=document.getElementById('mobNumber').value;
var data = {"countryCode":ccode, "mobileNumber": number};
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/sms/sendotp.php?action=generateOTP',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',               
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        var resp = JSON.parse(response)
        console.log(resp.status);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
        console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
             }
           });
          }
        function verifyOTP() {
             var data = {"countryCode": "country code", "mobileNumber": "Mobile number to be verified","oneTimePassword":"One time password"};
               $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/sms/sendotp.php?action=verifyOTP',
              type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',                
             data: data,
              success: function(data){
                  var resp = JSON.parse(response)
                console.log(resp.status);
            },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
                console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
       }
        }) ;
     }
       </script>

 <div class="send-otp">
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
 <label>Enter your phone number</label>
 <div class="clearfix">
   <input id="cCode" type="text" name="countryCode" placeholder="91" style="float:left; width:20%; margin-right:3%; color=#111111;">
<input id="mobNumber" type="text" name="number" placeholder="98XXXXXXXX" style="float:left; width:77%;color=#111111;">
</div><button onclick="sendOTP();" class="btn-primary btn">Send OTP</button>          </form>
```

Comment: usually this error occurs when the DNS isnt resolving.. try to use your localhost IP instead

Comment: no it showing same error